How can I add a border around a BarMark?
I am working with Apple's Charts framework and displaying a bar chart using BarMark to visualize data points. However, I want to add a visible border or outline around each bar to make them stand out more. I successfully added a border around the entire chart, but how can I add a border to each individual bar?
Here's a simplified version of my code for context:
import Charts

    Chart {
        ForEach(matchs, id: \.day) { match in
            BarMark(x: .value("day", match.day),
                    y: .value("point", match.point)
                )
                .opacity(1.0)
                .foregroundStyle(.red)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0))
        }
    }
    .chartPlotStyle { content incontent.border(.white, width: 1)}
    .frame(height: 250)


You are using Apple's Charts framework and not a 3rd-party library, correct?

Yes, that's correct. I'm using SwiftCharts, and I finally found the solution!

The solution is by using the annotation, and this is how it looks:
Chart {
    ForEach(matchs, id: \.day) { match in
        BarMark(x: .value("day", match.day),
                y: .value("point", match.point)
        )
        .opacity(1.0)
        .foregroundStyle(.red)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0))
        // Here is the addition of a border to the BarMark.
        .annotation(position: .overlay) {
                   Rectangle()
                    .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 1)
                      .padding(-4)
        }
    }
}
.frame(height: 250)
// Here is the addition of a border to whol Chart
.chartPlotStyle { content in
       content.border(.white, width: 1)
}
.padding(8)

